# Out of eye or with eye

Tags: spoken-english

Someone is having a vision problem.(that person can't see clearly wity one eye)So what should be used:

> I can't see **with** my left eye.
>
> I can't see **out of** my left eye.

What would sound more natural and idiomatic?(which will be more likely to be used in day-to-day conversations?) And do my sentences give you a feelig of complete or partial blindness? (What can be used for both?)

> I can bearly see **with/out of** my left eye.
>
> I can't see clearly **with /out of** my left eye.

Comment: Both make sense to me. I wouldn't be surprised to hear either of them, and I would definitely understand them to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both 100% valid, equally common, and mean the same thing.

The use of "out of" with an eye is a little bit more colloquial, while "with" would be something a more educated person (or a person with a more formal pattern of speech) might be slightly more likely to say.

I would tend to use "out of" in an all or nothing context

> I can't see out of this eye at all

while I would be more likely to use "with" when being a bit more descriptive

> Things are blurry when I look with only this eye

But either one works in either case. In normal speech I would be more likely to say "out of" most of the time, I think.